# LINQ query throw an exception when to get a count of a type

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq, .net-6.0, xunit

I write a test to filter a list.

Service.cs

```
public async Task<GetAllParticipantsDto> ListAllAsync(GetAllParticipantsRequest queryModel)
{
    int count = 0;

    var participantsList = participantRepository.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(a => a.ParticipantConnections)!.ThenInclude(a => a.Connection)
            .Include(a => a.ParticipantApplicationUsers)!.ThenInclude(a => a.ApplicationUser)
            .AsQueryable();



    if (participantsList != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(queryModel.RelatedConnection))
    {
        participantsList = participantsList.Where(x => x.ParticipantConnections.Any(y => y.Connection.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(queryModel.RelatedConnection.ToLower())) || x.ParticipantConnections.Any(y => y.Connection.LastName.ToLower().Contains(queryModel.RelatedConnection.ToLower())) ||
        x.ParticipantConnections.Any(y => (y.Connection.FirstName.ToLower()+ y.Connection.LastName.ToLower()).Contains(queryModel.RelatedConnection.ToLower())) || x.ParticipantConnections.Any(y => (y.Connection.FirstName.ToLower() +" "+ y.Connection.LastName.ToLower()).Contains(queryModel.RelatedConnection.ToLower())));
        count = participantsList.Count(); //  NullReferenceException Exception thrown in this line
    }
}
```

unit test

```
public async void ListAllAsync_ShouldReturn_FilterByBy_RelatedConnection()
{
    var query = new GetAllParticipantsRequest()
    {   // others null
        RelatedConnection = "Alice Doe, Bob Doe"
    };
    Func<DSMP.ApplicationCore.Entities.Participant, bool> exists = n => true;  // prepare Func outside of Setup

    //1 - create a List<T> with test items
    var participantList = ParticipantMockData.ListAllAsyncEntity();

    //2 - build mock by extension
    var mock = participantList.AsQueryable().BuildMock();

    //3 - setup the mock as Queryable for Moq
    _participantRepository.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking(false)).Returns(mock);

    var sut = new ParticipantService(
        _participantRepository.Object, _participantSupportNeed.Object, _participantConnection.Object, _participantDisability.Object, _participantMedicalCondition.Object, _supportNeed.Object, _disability.Object, _medicalCondition.Object, _participantApplicationUser.Object, _appLogger.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await sut.ListAllAsync(query);

    // Assert
}
```

The exception

> Message - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

> StackTrace -
> "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

I could not find why this error occur.
Can any one help me?

Comment: Which line you get this error?

Comment: In service, `count = participantsList.Count(); //  NullReferenceException Exception thrown in this line`

Comment: That's because at that point the entire query `participantsList` is first executed. It's up to you to analyze what's null in the query. We can't debug your code.

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake in the data. The list had an empty object. I removed it. now works fine